# Запустить war файл

Tags: jsp, servlet, java

Всем добрый день. )

У меня возникла проблема с проектом. В общем, обычная связка jsp servlet, когда проект запускаю на нетбинсе (со своим томкат), никаких проблем все работает. А как хочу запустить в другом компе через war файл, устанавливаю apache tomcat, загружаю  war файл и открываю, на первой же странице авторизации выходит ошибка HTTP Status 404 - /admin/register. То есть говорит  The requested resource is not available. Смотрю в гугле, выдал что-то вроде неправильно указанных названий сервлетов или путей на web.xml, но дело в то, что у меня вообще нет такого xml файла в проекте.

Что я делаю не так? Может, у кого-то были такие проблемы? Помогите. :)

Comment: Какая версия Tomcat? Куда подкладываете war-файл? Что конкретно происходит в логах tomcat'а?

Comment: Что правда совсем совсем без web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблемы с основной конфигурацией Tomcat. Проблема с правами доступа. Точнее сказать не могу, давно с ним не работал. Там есть конфигурационный файлик, в котором настраивается уровни доступа. Может, там поковыряться надо.

Comment: я уже решила, действительно дело оказалось в неправильной версии томката:) 
стыдно))) но все равно всем спасибо за ответы)